# Where do files emitted by file-loader live in the output bundle?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader, webpack-file-loader

I have a simple *Hello World*-type web application. It simply displays the text "Hello, World!" with a background image. The app works as expected, but I would like to better understand how the image is bundled and served.

When I run `webpack-dev-server`, I see that my background image `pattern.svg` is emitted as `e78b561561e0911af1eae4c8c3de25c4.svg`:

```
                               Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
e78b561561e0911af1eae4c8c3de25c4.svg    27.7 kB          [emitted]
                     index_bundle.js     748 kB       0  [emitted]  main
                          index.html  435 bytes          [emitted]
```

If I visit `http://localhost:[my-port]/e78b561561e0911af1eae4c8c3de25c4.svg`, the image is served as expected. However, if I look at webpack's output in my `dist` folder, I only see two files:

```
# ls -al dist
total 260
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     45 Oct 17 15:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root    132 Oct 17 15:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    435 Oct 17 15:43 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 260176 Oct 17 15:43 index_bundle.js
```

What happens when I request `http://localhost:[my-port]/e78b561561e0911af1eae4c8c3de25c4.svg`? Where does the image live in webpack's output bundle, and how does the server know to map `http://localhost:[my-port]/e78b561561e0911af1eae4c8c3de25c4.svg` to this image? For reference, see contents of relevant files below.

### /app/index.html

```
...
<body>
  <div id='app' />
</body>
...
```

### /app/index.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
require('./styles/main.css');
...
```

### /app/styles/main.css

```
#app {
  background-image: url('../images/pattern.svg');
}
```

### /webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: 'dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg)$/i,
        loader: 'file'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
  ]
}
```